# JQuery zooming multiple items, aspect ratio

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me maintain gap between these boxes when zooming, I think anyone who has done multimedia / graphics will know this algorithm required

I have created a separate fiddle for it.
http://jsfiddle.net/p9BJ8/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="canvas">
        <div id="innercanvas">
            <div class="square" style="top:30px; left:30px; width:40px; position:absolute; height:40px; background-color:red"></div>
            <div class="square" style="top:100px; left:90px; width:40px; position:absolute; height:40px; background-color:red"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="ZoomIn" value="+" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var zoom = 40;
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#ZoomIn').bind('click', function () {
                zoom = zoom + 5;
                $("#innercanvas .square").each(function (index) {

                    $("#innercanvas").width($("#innercanvas").width + 5);
                    $("#innercanvas").height($("#innercanvas").height + 5);

                    var id = $(this).attr("id");


                        var _offset = $(this).offset();
                        $(this).offset({ top: _offset.top + 5, left: _offset.left + 5 });
                        $(this).width(zoom);
                        $(this).height(zoom);                   
                });
            });    
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p9BJ8/1/

I only changed a single line:

```
$(this).offset({ top: _offset.top + 5*index, left: _offset.left + 5*index });
```

The `index` variable comes from your function callback, and it simply equals the iteration number of the loop. So the first time through it's 5*1, the second time through it is 5*2. So the second square is getting moved down and to the left 10 rather than 5, which is necessary because the first square is both moved 5 AND increased in size by 5.

## EDIT

In response to OP's comment, this one keeps the distance between the objects a fixed percentage of their size: http://jsfiddle.net/p9BJ8/6/

I created the following function to compute the initial "gap percentage", which is simply the `gap's width / square's width`, and the `gap's height / square's height`. We're really just doing basic math with JavaScript, so hopefully the function is clear enough to you:

```
function getGapPercentage(){
    var squares = $("#innercanvas .square");
    var s1 = squares.eq(0);
    var s2 = squares.eq(1);
    var s1top = parseInt(s1.css('top'), 10);
    var s2top = parseInt(s2.css('top'), 10);
    var s1left = parseInt(s1.css('left'), 10);
    var s2left = parseInt(s2.css('left'), 10);
    var h = s1.height();
    var w = s1.width();
    var gapH = s2top - h - s1top;
    var gapW = s2left - w - s1left;
    var gapPercents =  {
        top: gapH / h,
        left: gapW / w
    };

    return gapPercents;
}
```

From there, we just modify the line that sets the new position of the squares:

```
$(this).offset({
    top: _offset.top + (5 + 5*gapPercents.top) * index,
    left: _offset.left + (5 + 5*gapPercents.left) * index
});
```

Note that inside the `.click()` event I am calling the `getPercentage()` function again, but its only to show you (via output in the console) that the percentages are staying the same. Don't be worried by the fact that they actually seem to change slightly. That's just because the browser can't modify things by a fraction of a pixel, so sometimes the gap percentage is going to be very slightly off the original. But it will always hover very close to that original percentage.

Comment: Thanks Maxedison. What I was after was keeping the distance between the objects as a percentage also. Your solution is very close so far

Comment: Awesome work that's exactly what the doctor ordered. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: The ideal soltuion basically needs to zoom multiple objects, I can have 50 squares and zoom them all.

Comment: Then mark this question as answered, try to solve the 50 squares problem yourself, and if it doesn't work open a new question that specifically addresses what went wrong there.